# Javascript gauge with multiple pointers or how to build it (how to rotate)?

Tags: javascript, charts, gauge

I'm trying to find a gauge which uses multiple pointers because I need to show information of multiple objects at same time. It seems that there isn't one, but maybe is just hidden in the network. (Note: as gauge I mean [this](http://bernii.github.com/gauge.js/))

Anyway, if no one has built it before, I can write it by myself but my biggest problem is how to make the pointer "rotate" (without using canvas) in all browsers. All I can think about is css3 rotation but that will not support older browsers. Are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check our [Perfect Widgets](http://perfectwidgets.com). This pure JavaScript SVG library allows you to design any Gauge you want and add it to HTML page. For example you can see the gauge with two points [here](http://perfectwidgets.com/demo/index.html#Gauges/0).

Comment: Thanks, this is quite useful. Better than the other solution.